# To print only 3 consecutive character from given string

Tags: java, string, char

I want to print only 3 same consecutive characters from the given String as below
if input is:

```
"aasssfddddvvv"
```

then I should get output as output:

```
sss
vvv 
count=2
```

This is my requirement, please help me in this.

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        char s[] = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {

            if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2] && s[i] == s[i + 3]) {
                System.out.println(s[i]);

            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: i want to print the letters which are repeated 3 times help me with the logic

Comment: In which way does your code not match the requirement? Pleas show the output and describe the difference to the desired output.

Comment: You should be more clear with the question! As far as I can see, the code you have provided checks for 4 repeating letters and not 3.

Comment: Do you like what happens if you have more repetitiona than you are looking for? Looks like you get n repetitions in output if there are M+n repetitions in input. Your question wants M==3, your code has M==4 (credits to @SwapnilPandey ).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a departure from the more manual method being used in the OP.  But, this is fairly straightforward to handle uses a regex pattern matcher in Java.  We can match on the pattern `(.)\\2*`, to capture all groups of similar letters.  Then, just print out the groups which occur as 3 only.

```
String line = "aasssfddddvvv";
String pattern = "((.)\\2*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1).length() == 3) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}

sss
vvv
```

### Demo

Comment: I did not downvote. I did however have a feeling based on speculation. I offer it as a different angle on your answer which might help to understand a downvote: The answer seems to leave the (speculated) area of competence of OP and/or the speculated purpose of the OP to understand the logic. It is a technically superior answer, which just might fail to appropriatly target the audience. It might  get more upvotes (undownvote) if an additional part is added which explains the needed logic or maybe even shows code for it. That however is already provided by other answers. Maybe just refer...

Comment: @Yunnosch You're right, and I agree, but at at the same time another engineer who has the same problem as the OP might want to see various methods.  Oh well, I have eaten my -2 for the day!

Comment: I like you answer (cannot upvote twice however ;-) ). If you just set the scope for your answer, i.e. introduce that this is using advanced tools, I expect that others will agree. Maybe even the downvoter...

Answer (score 2):

**First problem is that,** you try to reach lenght+2th index of array in **for** which is not possible.

Assume String lenght is 5

```
0:  0 1 2
1:  1 2 3
2:  2 3 4
3:  3 4 (5)
4:  4 **(5) (6)**
```

As you can see, you try to reach **5** which is not part of string. So try

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 2; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++)
```

Tip: You can get this from error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   13

It says you try to reach index which you can't.

**Second problem** you check 4 char in if condition. Use:

```
if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2])
```

instead of

```
if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2] && s[i] == s[i + 3])
```

Comment: i got it, but if my string has "aasssffffvvv" it is printing as 's f f v'

Comment: And you do not like that? Please be clear in your question. Show output compared to desired output and explain.

Comment: you can also check if s[i] !=s[i+3] to insure that you get characters which are repeated *only* 3 times.

Comment: @Swapnil Make an answer, you are ahead of the other answerers.

Comment: I think, new learners shouldn't be replied with best answer. We should answer them only what they are asking. So they can learn better.

Answer (score 0):

You cant check.cells i + 2 and i + 3 because you will cross the array bounds when you will reach i = length -2,
You should count the sequence and check if the length is sufficient, if so print, also, in your example you are comparing 4 cells so the length will be 4 and not 3, start the seq in 1 because when you are reading a single char its a sequence of 1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        char s[] = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();
        int seqLen = 3;
        int cnt = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {

            if (s[i] == s[i - 1]) {
                cnt++;
             }
            if((cnt==seqLen)&&((s[i] !=s[i - 1] || i == s.length)){
                 if(cnt == seqLen)
                 {
                     for(int j= 0; j<seqLen; j++)
                     {
                         System.out.println(s[i - 1]);
                      }
                 }
                 cnt=1;
            }          
        }
    scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate the addditional insight this answer provides when compared to the other, older and upvoted one.

Comment: Now you explained the same, I was asking for the **additional** insight. I.e. what I want to say is "Why make a basically identical answer?" That would make sense if you manage to explain clearer, easier to understand and/or easier to read. But that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: I see. And now would you like to improve the chances of your answer by improving it?

Comment: This doesn't handle the end of the string correctly. If the string ends with `BAAA`, it won't print `A`.

Answer (score 0):

First Iterate through your `char[]` array. Then, in your `if` statement,

- First make sure that there are more than 2 characters left in the array.
- Then compare the `s[i]` with the next char(`s[i+1]`) and the char after next(`s[i+2]`)

---

Replace this part of your code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (i < s.length - 2 && s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2]) {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the main logic of your code with this.
Here we are checking if there are **only** 3 repeating characters. by making sure that the fourth character is different.

```
int count=0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 3; i++) {
    if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2] && s[i] != s[i + 3]) {
        System.out.println(s[i]+s[i]+s[i]);
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("count="+count);
```

Comment: Doesn't quite handle the end of the string correctly. For example, if the string ends with `BAAA`, you don't detect the `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        char s[] = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();
        int count=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 3; i++) {

            if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2] && s[i]!=s[i + 3]) {
                System.out.println(s[i]+s[i]+s[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(s[s.length - 3] == s[s.length - 2] && s[s.length - 3] == s[s.length - 1]){
            System.out.println(s[s.length]+s[s.length]+s[s.length]);
            count++;
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want only a strict count of 3 consecutive character.  If that's the case, even after fixing the issues in your code (without changing the overall logic), it will print the `ddd` twice.  Here is the output of the fixed code:

```
sss 
ddd
ddd
vvv
count=4
```

What I meant by the fixed code is in handling these issues

1. Comparison is too long, fix: remove `&& s[i] == s[i + 3]`.
2. Condition needs to be adjusted to `i < s.length - 2`
3. Print out only a single char (probably is not a real problem)
4. Add a counter each time a match found

Here is the fixed code (**remember this is still not producing the right output you want**)

```
int occurence_count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 2; i++) {

    if (s[i] == s[i + 1] && s[i] == s[i + 2]) {
        occurence_count++;
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println("count=" + occurence_count);
```

One logic change is to have a separate counter that counts the consecutive characters and a variable that remembers what is the last character.

```
int char_count = 0;
char last_char = '!';
```

The basic idea is to go through our string and increment the `char_count` by one if it is the same and reset if it is different.  We also need to initialize it with a character that you're not planing to use as input, such as `!`.

Since we're going through the entire string, the for loop condition needs to go to the very end using `i < s.length`.

When we're resetting (when a different character is detected), we want to also check whether the previous one has `char_count=3` or not.  If it is a match, then increment the `occurence_count`.  We also need to do this one more time after the for loop because the check might not happens for consecutive that happens at the end of the input string.  Here is the code:

```
    int occurence_count = 0;
    int char_count = 0;
    char last_char = '!';  
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != last_char) {                
            if (char_count == 3) {
                occurence_count++;
                System.out.println(""+last_char+last_char+last_char);                   
            }               
            last_char = s[i];
            char_count = 0;
        }

        char_count++;

    }
    if (char_count == 3) {
        occurence_count++;
        System.out.println(""+last_char+last_char+last_char);                   
    }

    System.out.println("count=" + occurence_count);
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot but need one last suggestion is i tried this:       Enter the String: aasssddddfff
s
d
count=2             in this i'm not getting 'f'  in output

Comment: Hi @vicky, when I enter aasssddddfff as the input, I did get "sss fff count=2". Maybe my answer is too long explaining too much detail.  Please focus on the last code instead.

Comment: @vicky, I'm just guessing, perhaps the problem is in the for loop condition that wasn't reverted back to i < s.length, because we need to loop to the end of the string.  Please check the final code, it should be working.

Comment: @vicky thanks!  There is a way to officially accept an answer by clicking on the check next to an answer.

Comment: sorry bro, i tried but, i don't have 15 reputation points to accept your answer. personally i thank you.

Comment: ah, no worries!